# SDL Color shortcut

Tags: colors, sdl

I'm using SDL for a project of mine, and I want a shorter way of getting colors.

I want to do something like this:

```
SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, 0x0F380F);
```

Instead of this:

```
SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0x0F, 0x38, 0x0F));
```

When I was working in DarkGDK, you could do something like what I wanted, and it was great and simple, but when I try to do it in SDL, I get off colors.

Comment: SDL has many different pixel formats - it's possible that they may not map, depending on which one (my guess, anyway). You could use a macro: `#define RGB(r, g, b) SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 255, 255)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about defining this in one of your header files:

```
#define My_FillRect(screen, num)                               \
    do {                                                       \
        SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect,               \
                     SDL_MapRGB(screen->format,                \
                                num >> 16,                     \
                               (num >> 8) & 0xff, num & 0xff); \
    } while (0)
```

Then you can use `My_FillRect(screen, 0x0F380F);` and the compiler should be able to fold the constants that so that there won't be a performance loss.